# tmux prefix+tab not working

Tags: tmux

Moving from Ubuntu to Mac

Using latest Tmux

In ubuntu, prefix+tab will show a popup with commands w/ fzf to select

In Mac nothing happens

No keys attached to Tab

[image]

Comment: Did you copy your `.tmux.conf` from Ubuntu to macOS as well? It's most likely defined in there. If this does not help, please be more specific about the functionality you expect from Prefix-Tab ("commands w/ fzf to select" is hard to understand). A screenshot showing what you see on Ubuntu might also help.

Comment: Thank you. Nothing related to Tab in tmux.conf, attached a screenshot.

Comment: There is also `/etc/tmux.conf`. Prefix-? lists all the keybindings, what does it say for Tab? If there isn't an entry, try Prefix-: and run `list-keys` there.

Comment: Please add to the question any tmux.conf from the Ubuntu system, and its version number from `tmux -V` so we have something to compare. Add it as `text`, not as a screenshot, but don't remove the Ubuntu terminal screenshot.. How did you install tmux on macOS? I have the brew version (there is no base macOS version (Ventura)), and `Prefix-?`and `list-keys` lists nothing for `Tab`. brew doesn't install a `/opt/homebrew/etc/tmux.conf` either, so it's defaults are internal.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths I expect the OP to do Prefix-? and Prefix-: + list-keys on Ubuntu, to see what might be defined there (only have a Debian system here which doesn't have something for Prefix-Tab).

Comment: @nohillside Understood that. Trying to fill in the gaps by understanding what defaults to expect on the brew version. Then when OP replies with what's in their Ubuntu system via Prefix-? etc we can move on. I suspect a patched version in Ubuntu. If I have time later I may see if I can spin up an Ubuntu VM to check, if OP is not forthcoming.